# PowerShell .NET Core Unable to find type Windows.Storage.StorageFile

Tags: powershell, .net-core, windows-runtime

I'm trying to port a powershell script from `.net` to the newer `pwsh` with `.net core`. The following line loads [this class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile?view=winrt-19041) in `.net`, but gives an error in `.net core`:

```
 [Windows.Storage.StorageFile,Windows.Storage,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
```

The error in `.net core` is:

```
InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [Windows.Storage.StorageFile,Windows.Storage, ContentType=WindowsRuntime].
```

In the old powershell, the line prints out the following:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name         BaseType
-------- -------- ----         --------
True     False    StorageFile  System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass
```

I'm wondering if the class was moved, or since it seems to be an interop class, if it's just not implemented in `.net core` or is accessed differently.

How do I load this type in the newer `pwsh`? Also, is there a trick or certain place in the docs for determining what is available for `.net` vs `.net core`, ideally including interop classes?

Comment: the following looks like the "why" of it ... "Loading" of Windows Runtime assemblies fails in 7.1 Preview 4 · Issue #13042 · PowerShell/PowerShell — https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13042

Comment: That does look like the issue. It looks like they've defined one or more nuget packages for including winrt in pwsh if I can figure out which is the right one and how to use it...

Comment: yep ... and that is beyond my skill level. [*blush*] good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: lol, well, thanks for the link. I"m not sure if I can figure it out either but that definitely helps.